# Laravel Sanctum with uuid column in User model doesn't save tokenable_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum, sanctum

I'm try to use `Laravel 8.x` and `Laravel sanctum 2.14.2` to authenticate my API and UUIDs as the primary key for my `User` model.

My custom `PersonalAccessToken` model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as SanctumPersonalAccessToken;

class PersonalAccessToken extends SanctumPersonalAccessToken
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'personal_access_tokens';

    public function tokenable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('tokenable', "tokenable_type", "tokenable_id", "uuid");
    }
}
```

My `personal_access_tokens` migration schema

```
...
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('personal_access_tokens');

        Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->uuidMorphs('tokenable');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
            $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
...
```

My `AppServiceProvider`

```
...
use App\Models\PersonalAccessToken;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Sanctum::ignoreMigrations();
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if($this->app->environment('production')) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }

        Sanctum::usePersonalAccessTokenModel(PersonalAccessToken::class);
    }
}
```

When I try to get the token with `$user->createToken($user->email)->plainTextToken`, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tokenable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (admin@gmail.com, 85dbe44c32a999a01f4a97d9c9eab0710125a6ac5f861ab546a5822f61015b23, [\"*\"], ?, App\\Models\\User, 2022-03-20 19:16:43, 2022-03-20 19:16:43))
```

I think the cause of the error is that I am using `uuid` as the primary key in the users table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->uuid('uuid')->primary();
      ...
});
```

**UPDATE**

My `User` Model

```
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasUUID;
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    ...

    public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Sanctum::$personalAccessTokenModel, 'tokenable', "tokenable_type", "tokenable_id");
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for late reply. I answer with the solution for anyone who is having the same problem as above.
The problem is in my `UUId Traits`. We should use `boot magic method` as Laravel suggested when we want to create our own Traits.

Solution:

Using `App\Traits\HasUUID` with the correct code

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait HasUUID
{
    /**
     * Boot functions from Laravel.
     */
    // protected static function boot() <- This line is INCORRECT
    protected static function bootHasUUID()
    {
        static::creating(function (Model $model) {
            $model->primaryKey = 'uuid';
            $model->keyType = 'string'; // In Laravel 6.0+ make sure to also set $keyType
            $model->incrementing = false;

            if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()})) {
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the value indicating whether the IDs are incrementing.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the auto-incrementing key type.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }
}
```

And finally, add the `App\Traits\HasUUID` in `User` Model.

```
...
use App\Traits\HasUUID;
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasUUID;
    ...
}
```

No need to customize `Sanctum's Model`. Thank you so much @Hussain, @Dharman

Comment: Hmm...I was creating a trait with `boot()` function name and calling `parent::boot()`, but it's fail, and then realize that I have static `boot()` in the model that use the trait, removing the `boot()` in the model would work. but I need that. But with this way (using `bootTraitName()`) would work, without needed to call `parent::boot()`, and the `boot()` still exist in the model

Answer (score 3):

Is there any particular reason for you to create custom `PersonalAccessToken` model?

If it's just UUID that you want for the primary key of your `User` model, you can achieve it without creating the custom `PersonalAccessToken` model.

Your `personal_access_tokens` migration schema seems fine.

> I think the cause of the error is that I am using uuid as the primary
> key in the users table
>
> ```
> Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
>       $table->uuid('uuid')->primary();
>       ...
> });
> ```

This could be the issue. Try changing the column name to just id from uuid and see if it works

```
$table->uuid('id')->primary();
```

If you must use the column name as uuid for primary key, then try adding the following to your `User` model

```
protected $primaryKey='uuid'
```

By default eloquent assumes the name of the primary key column as `'id'`. This will let eloquent know to look for `'uuid'` as primary key column for User model.

Also since you are not using the default integer data type for primary key make sure you have the following in your `User` model

```
public $incrementing=false
protected $keyType='string'
```

You can refer to Laravel Documentation for
[Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

Comment: Also, change `$table->morphs('tokenable');` to `$table->uuidMorphs('tokenable');` inside 'personal_access_tokens' migrations.